# Change Leaflet attribution control position

Tags: leaflet

I am using in my app a WebView to display a Leaflet map.

Inside the HTML file I have the following credits and links:

```js
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=xxxxx', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
  '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
  'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);
```

This looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to place the attribution control at the top left corner for example instead of the bottom right corner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course you can control everything on the map;)

```js
let map = L.map('map', {
  attributionControl: false
}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


L.control.attribution({
  position: 'topright'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.css">

<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the position using

// HTML

```
<div #map></div>
```

// Declaring in typescript

```
@ViewChild('map', { static: false }) mapElement: ElementRef;
```

// Calling method

```
 loadMyMap() {
    this.map = L.map(this.mapElement.nativeElement,{
      
    }).setView([0, 0], 10);
    L.tileLayer('link for tiles', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(this.map);
 
    this.map.attributionControl.setPosition('topright');
  }
```

This also avoids the text 'powered By'