# In leaflet, is there a way to redeclare the position of the Measure tool after it has been declared earlier in the script?

Tags: javascript, python, html, leaflet, qgis

I am using QGIS2Web with leaflet which means that the absolute positions of all of the map tools have already been declared earlier in the HTML script automatically. Is there a way to edit the template HTML such that the position of these map tools can be redeclared later on and therefore moving them around the map window?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458278/change-leaflet-attribution-control-position - not an exact duplicate of this question (you'd need to post the relevant bits of code where the measure control is defined, editing the body of the question), but the `setPosition()` approach should work.

Comment: @IvanSanchez thanks that works for the zoomControl using the following:

this.map.zoomControl.setPosition('bottomleft');

However, the same doesn't work for the Measure or Search buttons. These are declared earlier in the script using:

var osmGeocoder = new L.Control.Geocoder({
            collapsed: true,
            position: 'topleft',
            text: 'Search',
            title: 'Testing'
        }).addTo(map);

Is there a way to redeclare the position variable later in the code without editing this piece of code? (This will make it easier for use with the tool).

Comment: Since the control is already being stored in a named variable, that'd be something like `osmGeocoder.setPosition('bottomright');`

Comment: @IvanSanchez perfect thanks! The syntax makes sense now. I'm guessing the same can't be applied to the following though as it's declared through L.Control?

map.addControl(new L.Control.Search({
            layer: layer_Test_Point_1,
            initial: false,
            hideMarkerOnCollapse: true,
            propertyName: 'id'}));

Comment: No, you would need to store that in a variable beforehand. But you can also change the instantiation of that control to include a `position` option.